Metal Strip current sense Resistor layout
I am using a current sense resistor in my design. I have a question regarding which end of the resistor to be used for connecting to sense amplifier. The footprint and the connection diagram is given below.

I can connect this sense resistor to sense amplifier as shown in the any of two configuration below.
May I know can I use any one from the configuration below. I can connect to sense amplifier from XY or I can connect to sense amplifier from PQ? Please let me know your thoughts.

In the datasheet land patterns are given as shown below.

I know how to connect CSM3637 and it is shown below.

But I am confused about CSM2512 connections.
[![enter image description here][6]][6]
Configuration 2:
[![enter image description here][7]][7]

Does the datasheet and/or application note give any layout guidance?

Should wire X-Q for high-current path ... and P-Y for sensing (as indicated).

use the big pads for the big current, use the small pads for the small or zero current, as labelled under the footprint.

You use the small tabs for the sensing leads. This method is called the kelvin connection.
It avoids any current flowing in the conductors to your amplifier that may offset the measurement. Remember, the resistors solder tab is part of this path.
If you use one large and one small tab for the current path there will be a thermal gradient since the smaller one will have a higher joint resistance. Don't do that, it causes unnecessary error.
Here is an example of the footprint as added in Kicad:
https://gitlab.com/kicad/libraries/kicad-footprints/-/merge_requests/573
You can safely pass sense traces of shunts under the shunt, there is negligible voltage because it's a shunt. The soldermask can handle it.
If you don't have soldermask, use vias, but keep both sense traces close together.

Thank you.I edited my question.I have a doubt about the orientation.Could you please check

@Confused I don't know if you're trolling now, but in SMD resistors the current path is from the solder tab, through the ceramic element, to the other solder tab...

You already should have your answer if you look at the land pattern:

The current sense amplifier connects to the E1 and E2 pads which correspond to the two narrow tabs on the part.

May I know how to orient CSM2512

The part appears to be able to be placed on the land pattern in either direction. It is a passive resistive component after all so there is no polarity requirement.
